# Where are Notepad++ configuration files?

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++

win xp sp3 and Notepad++ 6.6.7

I'm trying to find configuration files, so:

`C:\Documents and Settings\[User]\Application Data\Notepad++/stylers.xml`

I opened this file and change some settings, for example css identifier background color. Rastart Notepad but there is no change inside the opened css files.

And vice versa. If I make changes via GUI `(Settings - Style Configurator...)` changes are accepted, but there is no change in `stylers.xml`

So, where are the configuration files ?

Comment: For me it's `%APPDATA%\Notepad++`, which, I guess, is the path you mentioned on XP...

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, where is that folder `%APPDATA%\`. I can't find it, give me the full path, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how Notepad++ was set up.  If it was configured using the default options then the files are all in %APPDATA%\notepad++ - %APPDATA% is an environment variable which changes between windows versions but can be entered at the start:Run... (type start %APPDATA% in the start:Run.. dialog to open the folder in explorer - the address bar at the top will show you where it is).  echo %APPDATA% at the command line will also tell you.

There is an install option "Don't use %APPDATA%' which makes it put the config files in the install directory (mainly aimed at portable installations) - if that was selected then the files will be wherever the executable is.